# Should we split the GLSL tag by version since they are not cross compatible

Tags: discussion, tags

Today someone uploaded a GLSL documentation entry. Unfortunately there are several versions of GLSL and they are not backward or cross compatible. A working sample written for one version will not work in the other. Core keywords have changed, requirements are different, etc...

There's at least

- GLSL 1.20    // old-ish, desktop only
- GLSL 3.XX    // desktop only
- GLSL 4.XX    // desktop only
- GLSL ES 1.X  // phones and WebGL
- GLSL ES 3.X  // phones and WebGL2

So the problem is for both Q&A and Documentation it's fairly important the topics are well separated because they are NOT compatible. Someone unfamiliar with all the details and reading the wrong answer or docs will get lead down very mis-leading and frustrating paths.

Since I follow the [webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl) and [webgl2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl2) tags I thought about creating 2 new tags. [glsles1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glsles1) and [glsles3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glsles3) or something like that. Then writing a script to find every question with both the tags [webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl) and [glsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glsl) and changing that second tag to [glsles1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glsles1). Similarly questions tagged with both [webgl2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl2) and [glsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glsl) would have the second tag changed to [glsles3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glsles3). This would make the tags more explicit and less misleading. It would also mean the docs could be separated. Unfortunately I can't as easily fix all the OpenGL non-versioned [glsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glsl) questions but doing it for webgl seems like a start.

Note there is already a `glsles` tag but as pointed out above GLSL ES 1.0 and GLSL ES 3.0 are not compatible with each other so a single tag is arguably not enough.

Is retagging these GLSL questions something I should do or not?

Comment: Do all your knowledge becomes obsolete with the new version? Remember, tags are meant to be used by answerers.